# Checking authorized flag in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a rails app where I have added a boolean field named 'authorized' to the user model. Basically, I want to lock the app down such that only authorized users can access the app. I am trying to do this in my application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def authorized
    redirect_to root_path, alert: "Not Authorized" if !current_user.authorized?
  end

end
```

However, I am getting a redirect error when I do this as I have the root route set to a path where authentication is required.

I now I can do this check in the view or another controller, but I'd like to do it in the app controller as I want the entire app locked down.

Comment: The snippet as written redirects the user to the root_path if the current user IS authorized. Is that correct?

Comment: Opps! You are correct...fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here was my solution...

In the controller where I wanted the 'authorized' authentication I added...

```
before_filter :authorized, :except => :not_authorized

...

def authorized
    if !current_user.authorized?
      redirect_to not_authorized_path
    end
end
```

In my routes, I added..

```
get 'not_authorized' => 'my_controller#not_authorized'
```

...and added a simple app/views/my_controller/not_authorized.html.erb

Answer (score 0):

You can override these methods in your user model.

```
  def active_for_authentication?
    super && approved?
  end

  def inactive_message
    'my custom inactive message' unless approved?
    super
  end
```

I recommend you to change the authorized name by approved, I'm not sure but authorized sounds like an internal Devise method name.